# Python: Check if string is in list otherwise throw error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I would like to check if a string `s` is in a given list `valid_string`. If not, I want to throw an error.

```
valid_string = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
s = 'test'
if s not in valid_string:
# Throw error: ('"{}" is not a valid string. Valid strings are {}'.format(s, valid_string))
```

What's best practice in order to throw the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Manual Exception as follows:

```
valid_string = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
s = 'test'
if s not in valid_string:
    raise Exception('This is the exception you expect to handle')
```